# How do I search for a value inside a 2d list in python

Tags: python, list, loops, 2d

I am trying to create a program that searches for the exact value of the int in the first index of lists. I have to validate first the input before checking if it exists so I have this function:

```
fruits = [
    [1001, "Apple", "Red"],
    [1002, "Pear", "Brown"],
    [1003, "Banana", "Yellow"],
    [1004, "Grapes", "Purple"],
]


def validate_int(message):
    while True:
        try:
            intValue = int(input(message))
        except ValueError:
            print("Please enter a valid int. Try again.")
            continue
        else:
            for i in fruits:
                if intValue == i[0]:
                    print("     | ID exists. It is this fruit: ", i[1])
                    validate_int(message)
            else:
                return intValue


print("---------------------------------------")
print("Fruits")
print("---------------------------------------")
fruitID = validate_int("Enter FruitID: ")
fruitName = input("Enter FruitName: ")
fruitColor = input("Enter FruitColor: ")
new_fruit = [fruitID, fruitName, fruitColor]
fruits.append(new_fruit)

for i in fruits:
    print(i)
```

and when I run this code, it keeps looping and checking if the given input is int and exists, but when I append it to the list, it inputs the first input even if it's wrong, instead of the last correct input. The result looks like this:

```
---------------------------------------
Fruits
---------------------------------------
Enter FruitID: 1001
     | ID exists. It is this fruit:  Apple
Enter FruitID: 1005
Enter FruitName: Berries
Enter FruitColor: Pink
[1001, 'Apple', 'Red']
[1002, 'Pear', 'Brown']
[1003, 'Banana', 'Yellow']
[1004, 'Grapes', 'Purple']
[1001, 'Berries', 'Pink']
```

WITH THE CORRECT INPUT:

```
---------------------------------------
Fruits
---------------------------------------
Enter FruitID: 1234
Enter FruitName: Melon
Enter FruitColor: Orange
[1001, 'Apple', 'Red']
[1002, 'Pear', 'Brown']
[1003, 'Banana', 'Yellow']
[1004, 'Grapes', 'Purple']
[1234, 'Melon', 'Orange']
```

Instead of 1005 for berries, it returned 1001 even though it went through the validation. If I add the non existing ID the first time, it will append the right ID without any issues. It happens whenever I enter an existing ID for the first time. Any help would be appreciated, thank you

Comment: Why do you recursively call `validate_int(message)`?

Comment: It's unclear where `[1001, 'Berries' 'Pink']` comes from?

Comment: @TomDalton I edited my post, it's supposed to be my input, sorry!

Comment: "but when I append it to the list," - when / how are you appending to the list?

Comment: @TomDalton
new_fruit = [fruitID, fruitName, fruitColor]
fruits.append(new_fruit)

Comment: `Enter FruitName: Berries` where does that come from? I don't see the code for this prompt anywhere

Comment: It's quite unclear what is happenming here as it feels like there's code being executed that you arent showing. Please can you post the full code and all the inputs and outputs and explain where you think the output is no longer coreect. Also, please answer @timgeb 's question

Comment: @TomDalton Sorry, I thought this was enough for snippets, but it's supposed to be in my other function that asks for inputs. the rest were only accepting strings so I'm good with that, it's the int that I need to validate and check if that exists

Comment: @timgeb I was thinking I could go back to calling the function again instead of using a while loop in this one

Comment: @TomDalton updated, thank you, sorry about the trouble

Comment: Why don't you make `fruits` a dictionary instead of a 2-d list?

Comment: Ahh ok. It is now clear. Trace through *by hand* what happens in `fruitID = validate_int("Enter FruitID: ")` when you first give it an invalid Id, and then give it a valid ID. Pay close attention to the nested function call and what is returned by that function call, and then what is returned by the original function call.

Comment: @Barmar it is in our assignment's requirement that we need to use a 2d List

Comment: You're not doing anything with the return value from the recursive call.

Answer (score 0):

You're recursively calling your function, which effectively starts the while loop again when the int is found --> infinite loop. A better data structure would be to use a dictionary for this problem.

EDIT: I saw you edited your question with desired output. You can let the function return false if it already exists and use an if statement to check function output. I adopted your way of appending new fruits:

```
def validate_int(message):
    while True:
        try:
            int_value = int(input(message))
        except ValueError:
            print('Please enter valid input')
        
        # loop over fruits 2d list to find fruit
        for fruit in fruits:
            if int_value == fruit[0]:
                # you can join the strings to include color
                print(f"ID exists. This is the fruit: {', '.join(fruit[1:])}")
                return False 
        return int_value
    
fruit_id = validate_int('Enter ID: ')
if fruit_id:
    fruit_name = input('Enter fruit name: ')
    fruit_color = input('Enter color: ') 
    fruits.append([fruit_id, fruit_name, fruit_color])      

for fruit in fruits:
    print(fruit)
```